# OpenGL to GL ES 2.0 port: trouble in rendering

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es, 3d

I am new to OpenGL and was porting an existing application to make it work in iOS. The existing OpenGL code is below :

```
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&_colorTexID);
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&_depthTexID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _colorTexID);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, colorFormat, colorType, getColorBuffer(_HRenderTarget));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depthTexID);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, width, height, 0, depthFormat, depthType, getDepthBuffer(_HRenderTarget));
GLint mode[2];
GLboolean stencilMode;
GLboolean depthTestEnabled;
glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, mode);
glGetBooleanv(GL_STENCIL_TEST, &stencilMode);
glGetBooleanv(GL_DEPTH_TEST, &depthTestEnabled);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _colorTexID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depthTexID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUseProgram(getGLProgramObject());
if (_depthTest)
{
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}
else
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glVertexAttrib4f(glGetAttribLocation(getGLProgramObject(), "color"), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, _alpha);        
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(-1, -1);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(1, -1);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(-1, 1);
glEnd(); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUseProgram(0);
// Restore states
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, mode[0]);
glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, mode[1]);
if (stencilMode) glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); else glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
if (depthTestEnabled) glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); else glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

My GL ES change was to just replace the immediate mode quad rendering

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(-1, -1);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(1, -1);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(-1, 1);
glEnd();
```

with:

```
GLshort vtx1[] = {-1,-1,    1,-1,   1,1,    -1,1    };
GLshort tex1[] = {  0,0,    1,0,    1,1,    0,1,    };
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, &vtx1[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, &tex1[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

`GL_RGBA8` with `GL_RGBA8_OES`, `GL_R32F` with `GL_R32F_EXT`, and not using `glPolygonMode` as it's not supported. But it seems like I am missing something. It doesn't render and crashes giving error GPU feeling guilty for hardware restart.

My shader code:

```
        const GLcharARB* _udFragmentShader =
        "                                                                          \n" \
        "   uniform sampler2D udTexture;                                           \n" \
        "   uniform sampler2D udDepth;                                             \n" \
        "   void main (void)                                                       \n" \
        "   {                                                                      \n" \
        "     vec4 frag = texture2D(udTexture,gl_TexCoord[0].st);                  \n" \
        "     if(frag.a < 0.5) discard;                                            \n" \
        "     gl_FragColor = frag * gl_Color;                                      \n" \
        "     gl_FragDepth = (texture2D(udDepth,gl_TexCoord[0].st).r * 0.5) + 0.5; \n" \
        "   }                                                                      \n" \
        "                                                                          \n" \
        "";


    const GLcharARB* _udVertexShader =
        "                                                                          \n" \
        "   attribute vec4 color;                                                  \n" \
        "   void main(void)                                                        \n" \
        "   {                                                                      \n" \
        "     gl_Position = gl_Vertex;                                             \n" \
        "     gl_FrontColor = color;                                               \n" \
        "     gl_TexCoord[0]  = gl_MultiTexCoord0;                                 \n" \
        "   }                                                                      \n" \
        "                                                                          \n" \
        "";
```

Comment: any other GlGetError results?

Comment: Didnt get any error with GLGetErrow but on call stack it crashes while doing gpusubmitdatabuffers.

Comment: Callstack link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gwzyiak13pehl4/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-27%20at%2013.43.33.png?dl=0

Comment: I'd very much like to see your vertex shader. I am not sure why you are mixing and matching between generic attributes and fixed-function attributes. In any case, make sure the vertex attribute array for `glGetAttribLocation(getGLProgramObject(), "color")` is *disabled* since you are using a constant value.

Comment: @Andon i attached the shader code in question. I still have trouble, i fixed some other errors i had but again i have trouble with glbegin(Quads) block on how to bind texture n vertices. i wrote it as the below one:

Comment: GLfloat vtx1[] = {-1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1, -1,1 };
      GLfloat tex1[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 };
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
      glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vtx1[0] );
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
      glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &tex1[0] );  glBindAttribLocation(_udProgramObject->program, 1, "vPosition");glBindAttribLocation(_udProgramObject->program, 2, "texCoord");
       glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
       glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
       glDisableVertexAttribArray(1); but seems like something wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a wild mix of OpenGL ES 1.x and ES 2.0. ES 2.0 is **not** an extension of ES 1.x. ES 2.0 was a completely new API definition that has little in common with ES 1.x. This is also confirmed if you look at the official spec files (https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/gl.xml):

```
<feature api="gles1" name="GL_VERSION_ES_CM_1_0" number="1.0">
...
<feature api="gles2" name="GL_ES_VERSION_2_0" number="2.0">
...
<feature api="gles2" name="GL_ES_VERSION_3_0" number="3.0">
...
<feature api="gles2" name="GL_ES_VERSION_3_1" number="3.1">
...
```

You can see that ES 3.0 and 3.1 are specified as extensions of the `gles2` API, while ES 2.0 was specified as a new API with `gles1`. It is therefore not backwards compatible with ES 1.x at all.

This means that you either have to use ES 1.1 or ES 2.0:

- ES 1.1 is very limited. Most importantly, it does not support a programmable pipeline with GLSL shaders. I would also consider it obsolete at this point.
- ES 2.0 eliminated all fixed function features, and has only the programmable pipeline.

If you stick with ES 2.0 (which IMHO you should), you'll have to get rid of all the calls that are not available anymore. From a quick look at your code, this includes:

- `GL_ALPHA_TEST`: Replace with `discard` in fragment shader if your really need it.
- `GL_QUADS` primitive type: Replace with `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, etc.
- Immediate mode rendering (`glBegin()`, etc): Replace with vertex arrays/buffers and `glDrawArrays()`, `glDrawElements()`.
- `glEnableClientState()`: Replace with `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`.
- `glVertexPointer()`, `glTexCoordPointer()`: Replace with `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

Ideally you should avoid including any ES 1.x headers when you're using ES 2.0. This will allow you to see most of the incompatibilities at compile time, since the functions/enums that are not available in ES 2.0 will not be defined anymore, resulting in build errors.

Comment: I replaced the calls as suggested with following:  

    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
    GLuint _textureBuffer;
    GLshort vtx1[] = {  -1,-1,  1,-1,    1,1,   -1,1    };
    GLshort tex1[] = {  0,0,  1,0,    1,1,    0,1     };
            
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vtx1), vtx1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_textureBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tex1), tex1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Comment: glEnableVertexAttribArray(_vertexBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_textureBuffer);      
    glVertexAttribPointer(_vertexBuffer, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_textureBuffer, 2,GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(_vertexBuffer);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(_textureBuffer);   But now it crashes at runtime while trying to execute DrawArrays saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: i fixed the crashes, now part left is the passing vertex n texture coordinate to shader. I attached my shader in the question. i was doing like the below mentioned but something is wrong i believe GLfloat vtx1[] = {-1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1, -1,1 }; GLfloat tex1[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 }; glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vtx1[0] ); glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &tex1[0] ); glBindAttribLocation(_udProgramObject->program, 1, "vPosition");